# Display a message from PHP within AJAX call

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I have a favourites button calling an ajax request to update a MySQL database.

I would like to have a alert if there are duplicate additions or too many additions.

Can anybody see a way that I could show an alert if there is a duplicate addition? My code is below:

AJAX REQUEST

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'favaddDB.php',
    data: $('#addfaveform').serialize(),
    success: function () {
      alert('Added To Favourites');
    }
});
```

PHP

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=favourites", 'root', '');                                                                  
$query1="SELECT * FROM `$email` ";
$stat1=$db->prepare($query1);
$stat1->execute();// IMPORTANT add PDO variables here to make safe

//Check if fave adds >9 
$count = $stat1->rowCount();
$fave=$count;
if ($fave>9) {die(); exit();} // HERE I WISH TO RUN AN ALERT OR SEND BACK A MESSAGE TO DISPLAY
else {$fave=$fave+1;}
```

Comment: There's a whole lot of confusion in this code which is a sign you need a better foundation to build on. Do you have a good PHP reference to start from? [PHP the Right Way](http://phptherightway.com) is a good place to start, but you'll need other good examples to learn from. `die(); exit();` is some really strange code to see and suggests you're working from incomplete examples or bad tutorials. Remember that every function is [documented](http://php.net) and before you use anything you're not familiar with, take a moment to look up what it does so there's no surprises later.

Comment: Look into how to add a data field to the success function and let your PHP fill that in with info.

Comment: The easiest way to prevent duplicates is with a `UNIQUE` index (constraint) on a set of columns. The problem here is there's so little in the way of context we really can't say for sure what the solution is. What are you favoriting? How is it identified? How are users identified? Is there a persistent session? Where does `$email` come from and why is it being used as a table name?

Comment: She's just asking a simple question, not how to do the PHP programming in a correct, advanced manner...

Answer (score 0):

Just return the text to alert to your javascript:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=favourites", 'root', '');                                                                  
$query1="Query here ($email/similar should NOT BE HERE! Add them via execute/prepare.";
$stat1=$db->prepare($query1);
$stat1->execute();// IMPORTANT add PDO variables here to make safe

//Check if fave adds >9 
$count = $stat1->rowCount();
$fave=$count;
if ($fave>9) {die("Here is a message");} // HERE I WISH TO RUN AN ALERT OR SEND BACK A MESSAGE TO DISPLAY
else {$fave=$fave+1; die("Here is another message"); }
```

Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'post',
  url: 'favaddDB.php',
  data: $('#addfaveform').serialize(),
  success: function (message) {
    alert(message);
  }
});
```

Additionally, you should consider using JSON, to pass back entire objects to your javascript, and parse it there:

```
$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=favourites", 'root', '');                                                                  
$query1 = "Query here ($email/similar should NOT BE HERE! Add them via execute/prepare.";
$stat1 = $db->prepare($query1);
$result = $stat1->execute();// IMPORTANT add PDO variables here to make safe

// Tell javascript we're giving json.
header('Content-Type: application/json');

if (!$result) {
    echo json_encode(['error' => true, 'message' => 'A database error has occurred. Please try again later']);
    exit;
}

//Check if fave adds >9 
$count = $stat1->rowCount();
$fave = $count;
if ($fave > 9) {
    echo json_encode(['error' => false, 'fave' => $fave, 'message' => 'Fave > 9!']);
} // HERE I WISH TO RUN AN ALERT OR SEND BACK A MESSAGE TO DISPLAY
else {
   $fave = $fave+1;
   echo json_encode([
       'error' => false,
       'fave' => $fave,
       'message' => 'Current fave count: ' . $fave
   ]);
}
```

And in your ajax, make sure you set `dataType: 'json'`, which will automatically parse it into an object:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'favaddDB.php',
    data: $('#addfaveform').serialize(),
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function (res) {
        if (res.error) {
            //Display an alert or edit a div with an error message
            alert(res.message);
        } else {
            //Maybe update a div with the fave count
            document.getElementById('#favcount').value = res.fave;
            alert(res.message);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks  , i will give this s shot.

Comment: Having JSON results is nice, but there's still a long way to go here because the question is lacking in some fundamentals. A+ for effort though!

Comment: What exactly is it lacking @tadman? His request is pretty simple: Display a conditional message to the user, which I am demonstrating. Just because he posted some other code that may not make 100% sense (To me, it appears to be pseudocode because of the way he wrote `SELECT * FROM \`$email\``), the problem is clear.

Comment: I'm just saying a little clarification first would mean the answer's going to match the problem rather than just wildly shooting into the dark.

Comment: He gave psudeo code which showed a sample message at certain points in the PHP side. I don't think there is any shooting in the dark here.

Answer (score 0):

Simple is better, in most cases.
By returning `messages`, you can do whatever you want on the frontend side, depending on the message.

**PHP:**

```
<?php

$db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=favourites", 'root', '');                                                                  
$query1 = "SELECT * FROM " . $email;
$stat1 = $db->prepare($query1);
$stat1->execute();

$count = $stat1->rowCount();
$fave = $count;

if ($fave > 9) {
  echo "tooMany"; exit();
} else {
  echo "addedFav"; $fave++;
}
```

**JS:**

```
jQuery.post({
  url: 'favaddDB.php',
  data: jQuery('#addfaveform').serialize()
}).then(function (code) {
  switch (code) {
    case "addedFav":
      alert('Added To Favourites');
      break;
    case "tooMany":
      alert('Too many favourites');
      break;
  }
}).catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```